# Problema ao validar dados do formulário (nodejs, express, jquery e handlebars)

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

Tô com um problema em NodeJs na hora de validar um formulário. Eu quero que, caso haja um input digitado incorretamente, seja mostrado um alert pro usuário (sem sair da rota do form). Pra isso, eu coloquei um if pra caso houver esse erro, a rota pra onde eu enviei os dados inseridos pelo usuáro retorne um res.json com a mensagem de erro. O problema é que depois que o alert aparece e eu clico em ok pra fechá-lo, eu sou redirecionado para a rota que retornou esse res.json.
Eu tentei usar o preventDefault, mas ele não tá funcionando. E eu só queria esse prevent se precisasse mostrar o alert, pois caso não precise o usuário deverá ser redirecionado para uma rota onde irá ser exibida uma mensagem informando que o login foi concluído.

**A rota que renderiza o formulário**

```
Router.get('/signin', (req, res) => {
res.render('login-form', {
    layout: 'login.handlebars'
})
```

})

**A rota que recebe os dados do formulário, para validar e retornar um json contendo a mensagem de erro, caso haja**

```
Router.post('/check-signin', (req, res) => {

const [Login, Password] = [req.body.txtLogin, req.body.txtPassword]

 Client.signIn(Login, Password).then(response => {

    if (response.access) {

        res.redirect('/Auth/access-confirmed')
    } else {

        return res.json({
            errorMessage: response.msg
        })
    }
})
```

})

**Eu também tenho um client js onde eu uso o axios para pegar a mensagem de erro e um button.click pra, caso haja uma mensagem de erro, ela seja mostrada em um alert. Porém como eu disse, após eu clicar em fechar esse alert, sou redirecionado para a rota que retornou essa mensagem de erro.**

```js
const Axios = require('axios')
const $ = require('jquery')



const apiResponse = async () => {
  try {
    const {
      data
    } = await Axios.default.post('http://localhost:8081/Auth/check-signin')
    console.log('Valor de data: ')
    console.log(data)
    return data
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('Error: ' + error)
  }
}


//executado quando o usuário clica no botão sign-in
$("#btn-signin").click((e) => {

  const response = async () => {
    try {
      const res = await apiResponse()   
      if(res.errorMessage){
        alert(res.errorMessage)
        e.preventDefault()
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(`Error: ${error}`)
      return false
    }
  }

  response()

})
```

Comment: mas não é na rota do form que dá a mensagem de erro? ou vc criou uma rota pra dar o alerta de erro?

Comment: A rota /check-signin recebe os dados enviados pelo formulário e faz a validação deles. Se os dados forem inválidos ela retorna um json. No lado do cliente eu tô usando o axios pra quando o usuário clicar no botão ele ir na rota e verificar se há um json retornado. Caso haja, será exibido um alert na tela do usuário. O problema é que o axios parece estar indo na rota /check-signin antes de os dados enviados da rota anterior chegarem nela.

Comment: mas esses dados retornam em algum momento? parece que `Axios.default.post` não existe, seria algo como `Axios.post`, segundo a documentação. Não uso axios

Comment: Bom, ele estava retornando os dados, o problema é mesmo o fato de estar indo pra outra janela. E usando o preventDefault no button, os dados não são enviados.